# send text data with formdata via Axios post

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, multipartform-data

I am sending over a PDF file in formdata with an Axios post request.  So that file will get uploaded/saved to a folder on the server.  I'm using multer on the server to save the file.  And that works great.

Now I also want to add some fields to the DB related to the file.  One is the generated file name that gets generated right before the file is saved.  So I don't want to make a round trip back to the client and then make another call out to the server to update the DB.  So I want a send a few text strings along with the formdata.  But no matter what I try, I cannot read any text data from that formdata object in my Node code.  FYI I am using Express on my Node server.

Client side code that kicks off the upload process: (notice I am attempting to append additional fields to the formdata object)

```js
const uploadFilesAsync = () => {
        const data = new FormData();
        const filenames = [];
        uploadedFiles.forEach((f) => {
            filenames.push(f.name);
            data.append('file', f);
        });

        const fileInfo = {
            customer: selectedCustomer,
            load: selectedLoad,
            filenames
        };
        data.append('customer', selectedCustomer);
        data.append('load', selectedLoad);
        data.append('filenames', filenames.toString());

        // I also tried the following and then passing fileInfo in with data and setLoaded
        const fileInfo = {customer: selectedCustomer, load: selectedLoad,
filenames: filenames.toString()};

        uploadFiles(data, setLoaded)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('uploadFiles res: ', res);
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    // addFileInfoToDB(fileInfo)
                    //  .then((r) => console.log('addFileInfoToDB: ', r))
                    //  .catch((e) => console.log({ e }));
                }
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    };
```

And then the client side function `uploadFiles`:

```js
export const uploadFiles = (data, setLoaded) => {
    console.log({ data });
    const config = {
        onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
            const percentCompleted = Math.round(
                (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
            );
            setLoaded(percentCompleted);
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    };

    // and then here if I passed in the fileInfo object, I tried sending `{data, fileInfo}`
    // instead of just data, but that broke file upload portion too
    return axios
        .post(baseURL + '/SDS/upload', data, config)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log({ response });
            return response;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            return Promise.reject(e);
        });
};
```

And finally the server side function that does all the work:

```js
static async uploadSDS(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        let uploadSuccess = false;
        upload(req, res, async function(err) {
            if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                // return res.status(500).json({ Error1: err });
                //return { status: 500 };
            } else if (err) {
                // return res.status(500).json({ Error2: err });
                //return { status: 500 };
            } else {
                uploadSuccess = true;
            }
            console.log(uploadSuccess);
            // return res.status(200).send(req.file);
            //return { status: 200 };
            // if (uploadSuccess) {
            //  try {
            //      const result = await SDS.addFileInfoToDB(req.fileInfo);
            //      if (result) {
            //          return res.status(200).json({ result });
            //      }
            //  } catch (e) {
            //      console.log(e);
            //  }
            // }
        });
    }
```

When I `console.log` the `req.body` it is always empty.

Comment: did you try `req.files` or `req.file` instead?

Comment: did you use a body parser?

Comment: @Jarrett I'm not having a problem uploading the file, that is working

Comment: @Anatoly no, i have not, is that what I need to do to get those additional fields in the formdata?

Comment: Hmm. Depends on if you are using Express.js or not

Comment: Yes, I am using Express.

Comment: oh sorry thought that might be the problem cause i had that before.